# issue upgrading from chart.js 1 to 3.5

Tags: php, chart.js

I am going through all of our PHP (V7.3) pages and upgrading all charts to the latest version.

On some pages where the chart data is part of a sub page or created from an AJAX call I get this error all the time

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'axis' of undefined
    at vo.parse (chart3.min.js:13)
    at vo._insertElements (chart3.min.js:13)
    at vo._resyncElements (chart3.min.js:13)
    at vo.buildOrUpdateElements (chart3.min.js:13)
    at oo.update (chart3.min.js:13)
    at new oo (chart3.min.js:13)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2), <anonymous>:18:19)
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at jquery.min.js:2
    at Function.globalEval (jquery.min.js:2)
```

My code has changed from:

```
<canvas id='chart_canvas' width='620' height='300'></canvas>
<script>
    var data = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
    var ctx = document.getElementById("chart_canvas").getContext("2d");
    var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, {
         pointHitDetectionRadius: 5
     });
</script>
```

to this:

```
<canvas id='chart_canvas' width='620' height='300'></canvas>
<script>
    var data = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
    const config = {
        type: 'line',
        data,
        options: {
            responsive: true,
        }
    };
    var myChart = new Chart(
        document.getElementById('chart_canvas'),
        config
    );
</script>
```

The data varialble is:

```
var data = {"labels":["2021-07-17","2021-07-18","2021-07-19","2021-07-20","2021-07-21","2021-07-22","2021-07-23","2021-07-24","2021-07-25","2021-07-26","2021-07-27","2021-07-28","2021-07-29","2021-07-30","2021-07-31","2021-08-01","2021-08-02","2021-08-03","2021-08-04","2021-08-05","2021-08-06","2021-08-07","2021-08-08","2021-08-09","2021-08-10","2021-08-11","2021-08-12","2021-08-13","2021-08-14","2021-08-15","2021-08-16","2021-08-17"],"datasets":[{"label":"Jobs Created","fillColor":"rgba(26, 188, 156,0.2)","strokeColor":"rgba(26, 188, 156,1)","pointColor":"rgba(26, 188, 156,1)","pointStrokeColor":"#fff","pointHighlightFill":"#fff","pointHighlightStroke":"rgba(26, 188, 156,1)","data":{"2021-08-17":"2"}}]};
```

I know the code is ok because I have tried it in https://playcode.io/

I just cannot understand the error message and there is nothing i have found on Google, appreciate any pointers.

Comment: What does `data` contain?

Comment: added to original post

Comment: the index data of `config` const is missing. changed to `data: data`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the culprit - prototype-1.7.js

removed it and all works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

In your data you only have 1 item. This will be very hard to see on the chart because there will be no line to draw between items.

Adding to that, the `data` in your `datasets` should be formatted [like this.](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/data-structures.html)

It looks like you are trying to combine `Primitive` and `Object` styles when you should be using either one. Because you are already giving labels, you only need to give the data like this: `[10, 20, 30]`

you can also give the data like you currently are giving. You just don't need the labels.

Comment: While you are correct that a single value in a line chart is hard to spot it doesnt solve his issue, also your reasoning for combining `object` notation and `primitive` should not be done is incorrect, this is actually someting that is supported so that you can choose where you want your points to be while still having all your labels

Comment: @LeeLenalee That would actually be a pretty helpful thing to add to the Chart.js data docs.

Comment: more info - it fails here in the chart.js file - const iAxis = iScale.axis; on line 4110